# react-native init AwesomeProject gives an error EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/node_modules/@react-native-com...'

Tags: macos, react-native, mobile, npx

After installing brew, watchman and node. I tried to initiate my first react-native application from the terminal on a Mac machine.

When I run the command like it says on [React Native Development site](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) - React Native CLI Quickstart for macOS and iOS target.

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

I get the following error

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/external/xsel'
```

I am logged in as an admin, so that is not an issue, and I have even tried "sudo", but with no success.

Has anybody faced a similar issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are having a permission problem try to change the permissions to react-native's folder with your username.

```
sudo chown userName -R [PATH]
```

to know your username run this command in the terminal

```
whoami
```

or just do the following

close all VS Code instances.

clean cache with

```
npm cache clean --force
```

install the latest version of npm globally as admin:

```
npm install -g npm@latest --force
```

clean cache with

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Try to install your component once again.

you may want temporarily disable your antivirus program and try again.

Comment: could you give the specific path? full path is in the question, could you specify?